# C# выдает ошибку: System.FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#

При компиляции выдает ошибку. У меня в задании первое число(b) должно бить задано изначально, а второе число(c) должен вписать пользователь. Числа (b) и (c) типа double. Я решил дополнить код так чтобы если пользователь вводит не то число ему предложило ввести его заново. Если вводить не то число то программа работает правильно без ошибок, а если вводить правильное то выдает ошибку. Так же если убрать метод "Console.ReadLine()" и задать правильное число изначально то все работает. Там где случается ошибка будет выделено звездочками.

```
using System;

namespace Lab_3_3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
            static void ckl()
            {
                double b = 3;
                Console.WriteLine("Перше число: " + b);
                Console.WriteLine("Введіть друге число - \"1.7\": ");
                //*************************************************
                double c = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());//*
                //*************************************************
                if (c == 1.7)
                {
                    double a = Math.Round(Math.Pow(Math.Sin(b), 2), 2);
                    double x = Math.Round(a + Math.Pow(c, 3), 2);
                    double y = Math.Round(Math.Pow(Math.E, Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(x))), 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("Відповідь: a = " + a + " x = " + x + " y = " + y);

                }
                else
                {
                    ckl();
                }
            }
            ckl();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Используй [Double.Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093596/reading-double-from-console)

Comment: Я думаю дело в локали машины, в частости формата чисел. В одних странах (и соответственно настройках) дробные числа пишут через точку, в других — через запятую. Скорей всего, дело в этом несоответствии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;

namespace Lab_3_3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double b = 3;
            Console.WriteLine("Перше число: " + b);
            Console.WriteLine("Введіть друге число - \"1.7\": ");
            //*************************************************

            double c;
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out c))
            {
            }

            if (Math.Abs(c - 1.7) < 0.1)
            {
                var a = Math.Round(Math.Pow(Math.Sin(b), 2), 2);
                var x = Math.Round(a + Math.Pow(c, 3), 2);
                var y = Math.Round(Math.Pow(Math.E, Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(x))), 2);
                Console.WriteLine("Відповідь: a = " + a + " x = " + x + " y = " + y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
    double c;
    if (Double.TryParse(inputValue, out c))
    {
        if (c == 1.7)
        {
            double a = Math.Round(Math.Pow(Math.Sin(b), 2), 2);
            double x = Math.Round(a + Math.Pow(c, 3), 2);
            double y = Math.Round(Math.Pow(Math.E, Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(x))), 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Відповідь: a = " + a + " x = " + x + " y = " + y);

        }
        else
        {
            ckl();
        }
    }
```